# Can't check first node's value with my target value in order to avoid duplication in my place_first function

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion

As always being this problem comes from a book's exercises.
Neither I am not studying data structures, nor the book is about that.
But, there is a chapter that is "Dynamic Data Structures". I've already finished this chapter.

But, I have problem with insertion. In my opinion, my function works correctly, except that it makes duplicate nodes.

I made a precaution for that but it doesn't work. Anyway, please forgive me because of my silly mistakes.
OK, Here my structure types for name lists.

```
typedef struct name_node_s {
char name[11];
struct name_node_s *restp;
}name_node_t;

typedef struct {
    name_node_t *headp;
    int size;
}name_list_t;
```

place_first function:

```
name_node_t *
place_first(name_list_t *old_listp, char name[11])
{
    name_list_t *new_listp, *cur_listp;
    name_node_t *new_nodep, *temp_nodep;
    temp_nodep = (name_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_node_t));
    new_listp = (name_list_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_list_t));
    cur_listp = (name_list_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_list_t));
    new_nodep = (name_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_node_t));
    cur_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
    temp_nodep = old_listp->headp;
    new_listp = old_listp;
    if ( old_listp->headp->name != name ){ // My first precaution for duplication
        while(cur_listp->headp->restp != NULL && cur_listp->headp->name != name) // My second precaution for duplication
        {
            if (old_listp->headp == NULL){
                strcpy(new_listp->headp->name, name);
                new_listp->headp->restp = NULL;
            }
            else if (old_listp->headp->name != name) { // Third one.
                strcpy(new_nodep->name, name);
                new_nodep->restp = NULL;
                new_listp->headp = new_nodep;
                new_listp->headp->restp = temp_nodep;
                ++(old_listp->size);
            }
        cur_listp->headp = cur_listp->headp->restp;
        }
    }
    else{
        new_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
    }
    return(new_listp->headp);
}
```

I call that function like this;

```
listp->headp = place_first(listp, "Mustafa");
listp->headp = place_first(listp, "Mustafa");
```

My output like this:
__Mustafa
__Mustafa
__Ataturk
__Ali
__Eisenhower
__Kennedy
Thanks for advance...

Comment: this is quite messy... what is `restp`? Why do you need a struct for the name?

Comment: There are probably other issues with your code as well, but for starters, you're comparing strings with `==` (and `!=`), which just checks whether the pointers are the same. Use `strcmp` to compare the contents of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
if ( old_listp->headp->name != name ){
```

you are comparing pointers, not the contents, you want

```
if (strcmp(old_listp->headp->name,name)){
```

The same applies to the other checks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dfan and @Daniel Fisher.

Now, I understood my silly problem.

I have made some changes to my function.

So what did I...

I've added this statement for checking first node;

```
if ( strcmp(old_listp->headp->name, name) != 0 ){
```

And added a for loop for checking other nodes:

```
for( cur_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
                cur_listp->headp != NULL && strcmp(cur_listp->headp->name, name)!= 0;
                cur_listp->headp = cur_listp->headp->restp) { }
```

If it returns null my other statements will execude otherwise the old nodes will return.

```
if ( cur_listp->headp == NULL){
...
```

Full function ( maybe somebody will need it):

```
name_node_t *
place_first(name_list_t *old_listp, char name[11])
{
    name_list_t *new_listp, *cur_listp;
    name_node_t *new_nodep, *temp_nodep;
    temp_nodep = (name_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_node_t));
    new_listp = (name_list_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_list_t));
    cur_listp = (name_list_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_list_t));
    new_nodep = (name_node_t *)malloc(sizeof (name_node_t));
    cur_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
    temp_nodep = old_listp->headp;
    new_listp = old_listp;
    if ( strcmp(old_listp->headp->name, name) != 0 ){
        for( cur_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
                cur_listp->headp != NULL && strcmp(cur_listp->headp->name, name)!= 0;
                cur_listp->headp = cur_listp->headp->restp) { }
        if ( cur_listp->headp == NULL){
            if (old_listp->headp == NULL){
                strcpy(new_listp->headp->name, name);
                new_listp->headp->restp = NULL;
            }
            else {
                strcpy(new_nodep->name, name);
                new_nodep->restp = NULL;
                new_listp->headp = new_nodep;
                new_listp->headp->restp = temp_nodep;
                ++(old_listp->size);
            }
        }
        else
            new_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
    }
    else{
        new_listp->headp = old_listp->headp;
    }
    return(new_listp->headp);
}
```